# How do I set up split-screen with guest account on Gears of War Ultimate?

Tags: xbox-one, gears-of-war, gears-of-war-ultimate

I'm not sure if I'm being entirely dense about this, but I can't seem to find an obvious way to set up 2 player split-screen for local co-op using a guest account on my Xbox One.

As far as I can tell I've signed in on the second controller using a guest account, but this doesn't seem to add that controller to a party, so when I try to start a game I see this:

[image: More Players Needed]

Is there something simple I'm missing? Or is this just not possible?

Comment: Have you tried using a normal/non-guest account for the second player? I don't have the game, so I can't test this, but it might be worth a try in order to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both users are signed in you have to be at the main menu, have the second player or guest player press the start button and that should load their user and after that you should be good to go to select campaign or versus and so on. If that don't work, after you already have both users signed in, quit the game and restart the game. This being a Xbox 360 game originally, you will need to press the start and options buttons on ones remote to set up said guest account on the Xbox one.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I have no idea how I didn't manage to do this the other day. I just wasn't getting the option to press the start button to join. Thank you.